# MSBuild: How to run custom target after _CopyFilesToPublishFolder?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, clickonce

I'm using Visual Studio 2013. I'm trying to publish a ClickOnce application from the command-line by passing **/target:publish**. However, I would like to do a few extra steps after MSBuild is done copying all the files to the publish folder. This is what I have come up so far:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(SolutionDir)\.build</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksLib>$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll</MSBuildCommunityTasksLib>
    <ClickOnceBuildDirectory>$(ProjectDir)\bin\app.publish</ClickOnceBuildDirectory>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.targets" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="FileUpdate" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildCommunityTasksLib)" />

  <Target Name="CustomPostPublishActions" AfterTargets="PublishBuild" >
    <!-- Create directory -->
    <MakeDir Directories="$(ProjectDir)..\Deploy\Client\Application Files" />
    <!-- Copy published website to deployment location -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CopyItems Include="$(ClickOnceBuildDirectory)\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(_CopyItems)" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)..\Deploy\Client" />
    <!-- Write publish.htm file for ClickOnce -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)\..\..\Build\publish.htm" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)..\Deploy\Client\publish.htm" />
    <FileUpdate Files="$(ProjectDir)..\Deploy\Client\publish.htm" Regex="{VERSION}" IgnoreCase="true" Multiline="true" Singleline="false" ReplacementText="$(ApplicationVersion)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Unfortunately, this is the order that the targets get run:

```
CustomPostPublishActions:
         Creating directory "C:\MyProject\..\Deploy\Client\Application Files".
         Copying file from "C:\MyProject\\bin\app.publish\DeploymentScheduler.exe" to "C:\MyProject\..\Deploy\Client\DeploymentScheduler.exe".
         Copying file from "C:\MyProject\\..\..\Build\publish.htm" to "C:\MyProject\..\Deploy\Client\publish.htm".
         Updating File "C:\MyProject\..\Deploy\Client\publish.htm".
_CopyFilesToPublishFolder:
         Creating directory "bin\app.publish\Application Files\MyApplication_1_0_0_0".
         Copying file from "bin\MyProject.exe.manifest" to "bin\app.publish\Application Files\MyProject_1_0_0_0\MyProject.exe.manifest".
         Copying file from "bin\app.publish\MyProject.exe" to "bin\app.publish\Application Files\MyProject_1_0_0_0\MyProject.exe.deploy".
         Copying file from "app.config" to "bin\app.publish\Application Files\MyProject_1_0_0_0\MyProject.exe.config.deploy".
         Copying file from "obj\Debug\MyProject.pdb" to "bin\app.publish\Application Files\MyProject_1_0_0_0\MyProject.pdb.deploy".
     1>Done Building Project
```

Basically, how do I get my target "CustomPostPublishActions" to run AFTER "_CopyFilesToPublishFolder"? Is it even possible? Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are predefined targets that can be overwritten to run before or after publish, update your script like this:

```
<Target Name="AfterPublish">
    <!-- Create directory -->
    <MakeDir Directories="$(ProjectDir)..\Deploy\Client\Application Files" />
    <!-- Copy published website to deployment location -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CopyItems Include="$(ClickOnceBuildDirectory)\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(_CopyItems)" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)..\Deploy\Client" />
    <!-- Write publish.htm file for ClickOnce -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)\..\..\Build\publish.htm" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)..\Deploy\Client\publish.htm" />
    <FileUpdate Files="$(ProjectDir)..\Deploy\Client\publish.htm" Regex="{VERSION}" IgnoreCase="true" Multiline="true" Singleline="false" ReplacementText="$(ApplicationVersion)" />
</Target>
```

This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724(v=vs.120).aspx) will give you an idea of the existing overridable targets and how you can work with them.